# Ember.js Utility Class

Tags: javascript, ember.js, module, ember-cli, ecmascript-6

I am new to Ember.js and Javascript in general. I am using [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/) to create an app that could use a DateUtil class to perform some date manipulation. I noticed that ember-cli has a utilities generator to produce the following boilerplate code in app/utils/date-util.js:

```
export default function dateUtil() {};
```

I am wondering how to write a utility so that I can use it across my application. Specifically, as an example, in a controller:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  startDate: dateUtil.thisMonday()
});
```

where thisMonday() would return the date of this Monday using moment.js like:

```
moment({hour:0}).day(1);
```

There would be many others similar to thisMonday() as part of dateUtil.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You simply need to import the ES6 module that exports your utility function, in each of the controllers that want to use it, like so:

```
import dateUtil from 'app/utils/date-util';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  startDate: dateUtil().thisMonday()
});
```

Note that the path is not necessarily `app/utils/...` though, you must replace `app` with the name of the app that you used when initially generating the app. You can verify what this is by looking in `app/app.js`, and looking for the value of `modulePrefix` within `Ember.Application.extend()`.

Comment: You can make the path a little less brittle by pointing to the relative location: `import dateUtil from '../utils/date-util';`

Answer (score 3):

Just import your class using the ES6 module syntax.

```
import dateUtil from 'app/utils/date-util.js';
```

References:

- [ES6 modules](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:modules)
- [ember-cli guide on modules](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules)